# How to change repositories location in gitolite3

Tags: gitolite

I've just installed gitolite3 and as a default it creates its "home" /var/lib/gitolite3

I want that folder to be somewhere else like /home/gitolite3.

How do I move it there?

All the references I found around the web turn around a REPO_BASE variable that is nowhere to be found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GL_REPO_BASE` is a variable you can set in your `~/.gitolite.rc` file.
By default, it [references `$HOME/repositories`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/lib/Gitolite/Rc.pm#L41).

But this isn't related to where you have installed gitolite.

You can **[install it](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#install)** wherever you want:

```
git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
gitolite/install -ln /path/to/wherever/you/want
gitolite setup -pk yourname.pub
```

---

The [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792589/user792589) added in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26066208/how-to-change-repositories-location-in-gitolite3/26066482?noredirect=1#comment40897373_26066482):

> I added this line to the `.rc` :

```
 GL_REPO_BASE => "/home/gitolite",
```

(mind the trailing '`,`')

Comment: I could not find that variable in my .gitolite.rc, where should I put it. About the setup, I did not install by cloning, but rather buy using the debian package and it did not give me any options on where to install it.

Comment: @user792589 1/ Indeed, the variable isn't defined by default. 2/ Don't use a package, use the clone: you will have the latest version installed wherever you want.

Comment: I added this line to the .rc : GL_REPO_BASE => "/home/gitolite", (the , is important I think). This worked. Thank you!

Comment: @user792589 Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command line to reconfigure Gitolite3:

`dpkg-reconfigure gitolite3`

In the second question the system ask you for repository place. There you cant set any location where you want to have gitolite3 repositories files.

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Valid only for Debian based systems anyhow.